# UserManager: DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

colleagues!

I am trying to create a BOT that, if any warning is found regarding these alerts, sends a direct message to the individuals involved. I have tried many methods as indicated in the documentation (https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/main/UserManager:Class#send), but none have worked. It always returns the error:

```bash
DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message
    at handleErrors (~\projects\node\biz-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:722:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (~\projects\node\biz-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1120:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (~\projects\node\biz-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:953:14)
    at async _REST.request (~\projects\node\biz-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1266:22)
    at async TextChannel.send (~\projects\node\biz-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:155:15) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined,
      thread_name: undefined
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Cannot send an empty message', code: 50006 },
  code: 50006,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/1169011873031659590/messages'
}
```

How could I resolve this? Here is my code:

```js
    if (type === 'opened') {
      const { authorsText, reviewrsText, passed } = DataBase.setConflicts(
        source_branch,
        has_conflicts,
        diverged_commits_count,
        authorData.discord,
        title
      );

      if (passed === false) {
        try {
          const userManagerInstance = new UserManager(client);

          await userManagerInstance.createDM(authorData.discord).send(authorData.discord, authorsText);
          await userManagerInstance.createDM(assigneeData.discord).send(assigneeData.discord, reviewrsText);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error al enviar mensajes directos:', error);
        }
      }
    }
```

> I receive client as an argument in the function that executes this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that `authorsText` and `reviewrsText` are not empty strings. You can do so with `if`-statements that `return` from the current function early if the strings are empty, preventing your bot from crashing.

```js
// other code...

if (!authorsText) {
    console.error('authorsText is empty');
    return;
}

if (!reviewrsText) {
    console.error('reviewrsText is empty');
    return;
}

// other code...
```

If you do want your bot to crash when unintended behavior occurs, then use Node's `assert` module.

```js
import assert from 'assert'; // ESM
const assert = require('assert'); // CommonJS

// other code...

assert(authorsText, 'authorsText is empty');
assert(reviewrsText, 'reviewrsText is empty');

// other code...
```

Using assertions in your code can help keep your code robust and prevent unintended side-effects if certain conditions aren't met.